# send async requests during long worker operation

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a situation where I have a processing function that can take a lot of time to run.
This function takes a progress observer as an argument and notifies the observer about advancement.

I would like to send async http requests to report said progress, and return back to the processing function ASAP.

```py
def longProcessingFunction(progressObserver):
    # processing in a loop ...
        progressObserver.updateProgress(x)
    # more processing ...
```

```py
class MyClass():
    def runLongProcessingFunction(slef):
        results = longProcessingFunction(self)
        # send last request to report results (ideally *after* last progress message) like:
        # requests.patch(self.reportingUrl, json={'results': results, 'progress': 1.0})

    def updateProgress(self, progress):
        # send async http request to report progress like:
        # requests.patch(self.reportingUrl, json={'progress': progress})
        # ideally handle the response on next progress update
        # (if it arrived by that time - otherwise on the one after it)
```

I tried using `asyncio`, but it seems that its main intention is to use a main event loop, and add multiple async tasks to it. I even tried applying a somewhat bizarre [run_once approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782377/is-it-possible-to-run-only-a-single-step-of-the-asyncio-event-loop) inside the `updateProgress` function, but apart from it really forcing my scenario on `asyncio` I couldn't get the app to wait for the last pending progress task at the end and send the results request **after** it (any [wait for all tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796294/when-using-asyncio-how-do-you-allow-all-running-tasks-to-finish-before-shutting) attempt fails since I'm never really in an `asyncio` loop - I'm using it to 'run once').

In my case, compared to how normal `asyncio` code works, whenever I'm running the `longProcessingFunction()` I'm blocked until it finishes processing (apart from the progress observer being called).

Looking for any reasonable architecture whether with `asyncio` or w/o it.

Comment: Not sure if it is the best approach, but I would in `updateProgress` only write the progress to a queue and exit. Then, in another task, I would process what I find in the queue. Whether those two tasks are implemented as asyncio or threads, it should work in the same manner.

Comment: Whether or not asyncio will be helpful depends on what `longProcessingFunction` does. If processing involves a lot of I/O, asyncio can help; if it's CPU-intensive, asyncio won't help. You'll want to looking into using multiple processes instead.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. For the record, it's a 100% CPU guzzler, weekend runner on relatively small inputs, shameless game theory algorithm I wish to understand someday. Surprising though that python would require another process to send a request and pickup the response later.