# Implement a Python WebSocket listener without async/asyncio

Tags: python, websocket

I'm running a websocket listener in a separate thread.
I'd like to connect to the websocket then do:

```
while True:
    msg = sock.wait_for_message()
    f(msg)
```

i.e. no async/asyncio

Is this stupid?  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No it's not stupid at all. I don't like or want to use async in python. I just hate it. I'd rather do things the old fashion way. Currently looking into this myself...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In absence of a better answer, I have found https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client which prove painless to use.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is about a websocket client. But I had the same questioning for a websocket server.  As a novice with asyncio and someone who likes the old-fashioned synchronous design, I was baffled to see that there was so little enthousiasm for synchronous server design. All the example I could find on the web assumed that the whole application was asynchronous, which might not be true.

So I propose this solution to wrap the asynchronous websockets module into a synchronous class.  Hope it can help somebody.

The idea is :

1. Create an event loop specifically for the websockets module
2. At each loop iteration, enqueue a "stop" event to update the event loop once. This can be done multiple time without issues. (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782377/is-it-possible-to-run-only-a-single-step-of-the-asyncio-event-loop))
3. Put data into queues for calling layer to read/write websockets

Note : Looking at the websockets module source code, it looks like the `loop=` input parameter is deprecated. I'm not sure what that means exactly, whether the author will remove it in the future or propose an alternative.  (See [here](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets/blob/main/src/websockets/legacy/server.py#L1030))

```
import websockets
import websockets.server
import queue
import asyncio
import time

class SynchronousWebsocketServer:
    """
    Synchronous wrapper around asynchronous websockets server by Pier-Yves Lessard
    """
    def __init__(self, connect_callback=None, disconnect_callback=None):
        self.rxqueue = queue.Queue()
        self.txqueue = queue.Queue()
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        self.ws_server = None
        self.connect_callback = connect_callback
        self.disconnect_callback = disconnect_callback

    # Executed for each websocket
    async def server_routine(self, websocket, path):
        if self.connect_callback is not None:
            self.connect_callback(websocket)

        try:
            async for message in websocket:
                self.rxqueue.put( (websocket, message) )   # Possible improvement : Handle queue full scenario.
        except (websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK, websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError):
            pass
        finally:
            if self.disconnect_callback is not None:
                self.disconnect_callback(websocket)

    def process_tx_queue(self):
        while not self.txqueue.empty():
            (websocket, message) = self.txqueue.get()
            try:
                self.loop.run_until_complete(websocket.send(message))
            except (websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK, websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError):
                pass    # Client is disconnected. Disconnect callback not called yet.

    def process(self, nloop=3) -> None:
        self.process_tx_queue()
        for i in range(nloop):  # Process events few times to make sure we handles events generated within the loop
            self.loop.call_soon(self.loop.stop)
            self.loop.run_forever()

    def start(self, host, port) -> None:
        # Warning. websockets source code says that loop argument might be deprecated. 
        self.ws_server = websockets.serve(self.server_routine, host, port, loop=self.loop)
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.ws_server)    # Initialize websockets async server

    def stop(self) -> None:
        if self.ws_server is not None:
            self.ws_server.ws_server.close()
            self.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.ensure_future(self.ws_server.ws_server.wait_closed(), loop=self.loop))
            self.loop.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Demo on how to use the SynchronousWebsocketServer
    clients = set()
    def connect_callback(websocket):
        clients.add(websocket)
        print('New client. Websocket ID = %s. We now have %d clients' % (id(websocket), len(clients)))
    
    def diconnect_callback(websocket):
        clients.remove(websocket)
        print('Client diconnected. Websocket ID = %s. %d clients remaining' % (id(websocket), len(clients)))

    server = SynchronousWebsocketServer(connect_callback=connect_callback, disconnect_callback=diconnect_callback)
    print("Starting server")
    server.start('localhost', 5555)
    print("Server started")

    while True: # Synchornous loop
        try:
            server.process()
            if not server.rxqueue.empty():
                websocket, message = server.rxqueue.get_nowait()   # Non-blocking read. We need to keep call "server.process()" 
                print("Received message from websocket ID=%s. Echoing %s " % (id(websocket), message))
                server.txqueue.put((websocket, message))    # echo
            time.sleep(0.005)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
        
    print("Stopping server")
    server.stop()
    print("Server stopped")
```

To test this server, I did this in my browser console:

```
ws1 = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5555')  
ws2 = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5555')
ws3 = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5555')

ws2.send('Hello World')
ws2.close()
ws1.send('Hi') 

// Killed server here.
```

This generated this output:

```
Starting server
Server started
New client. Websocket ID = 140097014008368. We now have 1 clients
New client. Websocket ID = 140097014017824. We now have 2 clients
New client. Websocket ID = 140097014018928. We now have 3 clients
Received message from websocket ID=140097014017824. Echoing Hello World 
Client diconnected. Websocket ID = 140097014017824. 2 clients remaining
Received message from websocket ID=140097014008368. Echoing Hi 
^C
Stopping server
Client diconnected. Websocket ID = 140097014018928. 1 clients remaining
Client diconnected. Websocket ID = 140097014008368. 0 clients remaining
Server stopped
```